# Pass a reference property in method parameter in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working in an Angular 8 project and I have the following question:

I want to do a generic validation method with parameters to pass it in an event.

This is component:

```
public isValid: boolean = false;
public input = string;

validate(inputExists,status) {
   inputExists ? (status = true) : (status = true);
   console.log(this.isValid1);
}
```

And this is HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="!isValid">
    <p-autoComplete name="input" [(ngModel)]="input" [suggestions]="results"  placeholder="input"(completeMethod)="search($event)" (onSelect)="validate(input, isValid)"></p-autoComplete>
</div>
```

But I can't assign the value to the property.

When I do the following, it found correctly:

```
validate(inputExists) {
   inputExists ? (this.isValid= true) : (this.isValid= true);
   console.log(this.isValid1);
}
```

But I want to use it to other validations too...What is wrong?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xguahz

Comment: and `status` is just local variable you can't use it in the HTML code

Comment: There is no such thing as a "reference to a property". The best you can do is pass the object, and the property name.

Comment: Uh, this entire function should be scrapped and replaced with `isValid = Boolean(input)` or (even shorter) `isValid = !!input`

Comment: Notwithstanding the other comments, but shouldn't the last bit of the ternary expression `inputExists ? (status = true) : (status = true);` be `false`?